# Hints for finding the ith word if all the words are listed in dictionary order

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have this problem. Giving 5 letters: A, I, L, S and T.

a. Find the ways to make a word that has 6 letters long, which begins and ends with a consonant, has 2 but no adjacent vowels and adjacent consonants must be different.

The answer is 648. I list the possible combination (CVCCVC, CVCVCC, CCVCVC) (C is consonant and V is vowel). Then I calculate the first combination: `3*2*3*2*2*3` which is 216. Same for others two, so I got 648 in total.

b. If all the possible words are listed in dictionary order, find the last word in the first half of dictionary (324th position) and the word after that. For example the list begins with LALALS, LALALT,...

How would I do that? I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: i dont know how to answer your question, but i think you've missed the no-vowel and 1-vowel cases: CCCCCC (3*2*2*2*2*2), CVCCCC (3*2*3*2*2*2), CCVCCC, etc

Comment: Sorry I just changed the question, the word should has 2 vowels

Comment: Hint: The word must start with S. Can you see why?

Comment: Because the word must start with a consonant and the letter S lies in the middle between L and T so the middle word must start with S.

Comment: Then how can I do the rest?

Comment: oh, @DanielMathias is right, i should have posted only HINTs.  see if you can figure out the 2nd letter, the 3rd letter etc., before looking at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding the halfway point in the dictionary turns out to exploit some symmetries nicely.  (I.e. finding the $i$th entry for arbitrary $i$ would have been doable but much more tedious.)

First, note that there are equal numbers of words starting with L, S, T.  So the midpoint of the entire dictionary is the midpoint of the S section, where the first two letters can be SA, SI, SL or ST.

- Number of words starting SA: (SACCVC = 3*2*2*3) + (SACVCC = 3*2*3*2) = 2*36 = 72
- nnmber of words starting SI: same as SA, 72
- Number of words starting SL: (SLVCVC = 2*3*2*3) = 36
- Number of words starting ST: same as SL, 36

So the midpoint of the S section is the midpoint of the SI section.  The 3rd letter can be L, S, T, with equal numbers, so the midpoint of the SI section is the midpoint of the SIS section.  Now onto the 4th letter:

- No. of words starting SISA = (SISACC = 3*2) = 6 = no. of words starting SISI
- No. of words starting SISL = (SISLVC = 2*3) = 6 = no. of words starting SIST

So the midpoint is exactly in-between the SISI section and the SISL section, i.e. SISITS (the last word of the SISI section) and the SISLAL (the first word of the SISL section).

Hope I didnt mess up somewhere.  :)

Comment: $3*2*2*3=36$, not $81$

Comment: @DanielMathias hahahaha, i shouldn't have done math before COFFEE :)